# Copy/Move data in char *buffer to a multi dimensional array of char info[4][10]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I've data sequentially read into char *buffer.
Then I need to get the string in that *buffer to be copied into a multi dimensional array.

so the first data from buffer will go to temp_message[0], the second read from buffer will go to temp_message[1], and so on.

Length of string/data is 10....that is why I declared temp_message[4][10]

My code:

```
  char temp_message[4][10];
  //receiving....
  for(i=0;i<IR_COM_NUMBER;i++) {
    if (wb_receiver_get_queue_length(receiver[i]) > 0) {

        /* read current packet's data */
        ***const char *buffer = wb_receiver_get_data(receiver[i]);***
        count[i]=0;
        if (message_printed[i] != 1) {
          ***temp_message[i][]=buffer;***
          /* print null-terminated message */
          printf("Communicating: received \"%s\" from receiver %d \n",buffer,i);
          message_printed[i] = 1;
        }
        /* fetch next packet */
        wb_receiver_next_packet(receiver[i]);
        message_printed[i]=3;
      } else {
        count[i]++;
        if (message_printed[i] !=2 && count[i]>20) {
          printf("Communication broken from receiver %d!\n",i);
          message_printed[i] = 2;
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: And what is the problem you are having with the code?

Comment: test1mybot.c:79:27: error: expected expression before ']' token. The line where
temp_message[i][]=buffer;
doesn't work.... I don't understand....

Answer (score 1):

To specify one of the temp_message arrays a second `[]` operator is invalid. That is the reason for the compiler error. Use `strcpy` or `memcpy` to copy characters from character arrays.

```
strcpy(temp_message[i], buffer);
```

`strcpy` is appropriate here provided the contents of `buffer` are NULL terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function [`strcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcpy.html) to copy the string in `buffer` into your string array `temp_message`:

```
strcpy(temp_message[i], buffer);
```

I found one possible pitfall in your question. You write that the length of your string/data is 10 but do you account for the trailing `\0`?

Comment: when we specify a string, if the length is 10, is the trailing null terminator counted in or is it an extra trail?

Comment: @ivanwong888899999 If you have a string with 10 visible characters then C will append a 11th null character at the end of your string in memory. The length of a string that you get with `strlen` does **not** include this final `\0` but only gives the count of visible characters. As a result you get that if you want to store a string with 10 visible characters you need an array with a minimum size of 11.